# Apache2 Proxy Error could not handle the request GET/

Tags: apache

I run a apache2 server on my suse machine. Also on this suse machine runs a SAP HANA Aplication. On My HANA server runs a Webaplication. So when i open the browser on my Suse an tips localhost:51069 then i can use this app. Because it runs on this port.

This Website should run on port 80 of my suse System so it can called from the internet normally with the browser. To do this i  want to forward this port with my apache Server. Here is my config for my virtual host static is the hostname of my suse server and can be solve to my local ip:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName static
 ServerAdmin me

 ProxyPreserveHost On
 ProxyRequests Off
 ProxyPass / http://static:51069/
 ProxyPassReverse / http://static:51069
</VirtualHost>
```

When i open the page i get the error

```
Proxy Error
The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request GET/

Reason: Error reading from remote server
Additionally, a 502 Bad Gateway error was encouterd while trying to 
use an ErrorDocument to ahandle the request
```

When i look in the error file i get see the erorr is the last error:

```
Error reading from remote server returned by 
/error/HTTP_BAD_GATEWAY.html.var
```

it is posible that the failure by my Service behinde 51069

Comment: First of all the ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse should look the same. Maybe it's just a typo here? http://static51069/ --> http://static:51069     But more importantly your vhost takes request for the port 80 and servername 'static' to write them to 'static'?! So you have a 2nd vhost with port 51069 and servername 'static'?

Comment: sry i write it false in the quesiton, thangs. 
static is the hostname of the suse machine  on which my service with port 51069 runs. Do i need a nother virtual host for it ?

Comment: Does your server Listen 51069 in httpd.conf? Otherwise, how should he know it's meant for him if there is a 51069-request? And yes, if you want to use both ports on one server for different purposes, you would need two vhosts. But I guess you just want your one site to be accessed via 51069 and not the default 80?! If so you shouldn't listen to port 80 at all, but 51069 and just use that port in the browser to call your site. Maybe you can give some more information on what you want to achieve so we don't recommend something you actually don't need ;)

Comment: When i add a Listen 51069 comand in my httpd.conf my apache server will not started anymore. Do i realy ned a second virtual host. The suse system should be open only on port 80, thangs for your help, i near to get insane =)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, now I understood what you are trying to do. Actually you wouldn't even need the vhost at all, because all the directives can be used in the standard server config as well.

---

But now for the two problems. First the easier part - **strange error page**

Apache tried to serve the requested URL, but an 502 error occurred. The Apache is configured to send all requests (including errors) to the backend (HANA). The backend wasn't able to deliver a 502 error page, so the Apache throws a 500 which you can see in your browser.

solution:
The **ProxyErrorOverride** [On/Off] directive allows you to choose where the error page should come from. In your case 'On' so that the Apache delivers the error page, even if the backend can't.

```
ProxyErrorOverride On
```

---

Now the trickier part: **Bad Gateway error from your hana server**

There are a lot of possible reasons for this, that's why it is tricky. Possible reasons include:

- timeout of answers from the backend
- unexpected format of the answer
- backend crashed or is unreachable (although this normally results in 503s), check your SAP webdispatcher just in case
- threads of HANA server time out

You should definitely check the SAP default traces. As soon as I can deduce a 'real' from your next reply, I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: i have added the ProxyErrorOverride On, but nothing changed. 
i have tried to create a small python server which listen on a other port. The port forwarding works for this server. So it must be a SAP HANA problem. I search now for the points on which you pointed . Because yes my ProxyPass and my ProxyPassReverse looks exacly like this

Comment: I don't know where your error pages are located, but assuming you use customized error pages on your apache, maybe in /srv/www/htdocs/error/... and also assuming your DocumentRoot directive points to /srv/www/htdocs your error pages are avaiable under yourpage.com/error/error502.html or something like that. If so, you can add ProxyPassMatch /error !   so all calls on /error are not (!) passed to the proxy. If you use other pathes, edit accordingly.

Comment: I have not defined error page location on my own, and under my  /srv/www/htdocs i can find no error folder.